# Array object to generic List<>

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

I need to have `List<>` object from an array object.
The problem is I do not know the type for my generic item by default.

```
public override bool Get<T>(string key, out T value)
{   
   var cachedValue = <SOME OBJECT FROM SOMEWHERE OUT OF SPACE>;
   if (cachedValue is Array)
   {
      IEnumerable<object> collection = (IEnumerable<object>)cachedValue;
      var item = collection.ToList()[0];
      Type type = item.GetType();

      value =  (T)(Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(type),collection));
   } 
   else
   {
      ...
   }
```

The snippet is like that...But also I have an exception

> "Constructor on type not found"

Any way, I have set value paramater from an Array object as `List<>`
Any help would be great.

Comment: Does the class which is getting passed to the Activator has a public constructor, which accepts an IEnumerable<object> parameter?

Comment: If you want help from SO, please post a [mcve] of your problem with the exact exception message you're getting.

Comment: please put some effort when asking question. what is `<SOME OBJECT FROM SOMEWHERE OUT OF SPACE>` exactly

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary sorry for that, but there is some logic which is not related with my issue, so I do not want people to be confused.

Comment: @KAI yes, the type for the activator has a public constructor, but I am not sure if there also IEnumerable<object> parameter. I will check it... But I guess there is IEnumerable<T> parameter which also should be ok.

Comment: How are you calling the Get method ? there you already make an assumption on what T should be.

Comment: Cant you just use `cachedValue.OfType<T>()` ?

Comment: @Dbuggy Get<List<Setting>>("SYSTEM",out value) is like this. .OfType<T>() gets the type as T but with no items in it.

Comment: You could also debug your "type" value for which type your Activator is trying to create for real. It might be a wrong one, if the expected one is really having the correct constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Type` which is being passed to the Activator is correct, than the class, which is getting passed to the `Activator` (as type) should have:

- a **public** constructor
- which is accepting one parameter: an `IEnumerable<object>` one

Answer (score 0):

You can do, assuming you pass `T` as the generic type the list is comprised of:

```
if (cachedValue is Array)
{
  value = ((Array)cachedValue).Cast<T>.ToList();
}
```

But in this case, your method signature would have to be:

```
public override bool Get<T>(string key, out List<T> value)
```

If you pass `List<type>` as your `T`, then you'd need a bit more work (you'd need to check if `T` is a generic list, and then extract the actual type from the list).

Comment: This Cast<T> would only work when you are sure that the cached contains values of the same type and every item can be cast to T.

Comment: @Dbuggy You could use `OfType<T>`, but if the OP's aim is to create a `List<T>` using the constructor passing an `IEnumerable`, then it wouldn't work and raise exceptions (same as it'd do with using `Cast<T>`). I'm trying to imitate the behaviour he was trying to achieve (which is not working because the constructor expects an `IEnumerable<T>`, and not an `IEnumerable<object>`)